# How to create a single value out of a list within a 3D dataframe in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, 3d

this is my first post here and a noob in programming so I apologize in advance for any unintended lack of syntax and appropriate technical vocabulary.

I have the following dataframe (excerpt) which, correct me if I'm wrong, is a 3D pandas df with lists (...arrays?) within the df having different lengths?

```
df=
    Genre                              Cast
0   Action, Drama, Comedy, horror      Brad P., Denzel W.
1   Crime                              Al P., Robert De N., Angelina J., Lupita N.
2   Action, Sci-fi, Adventure          Mark W., Jamie F., Mila K.
3   Drama, Crime                       Jessica C.,Emma S.
4   Thriller, Action, Comedy, Romance  Jennifer L., Tom H., Charlize H., Vin D., Denzel W.
5   Thriller, Drama, Adventure         Tupac, George C., Kevin S.
```

Now I want to oversimplify the list contained within the Genre to one string that I'll set as the Main_Genre

eg: if Main_Genre=[Action, Crime, Drama, Thriller, etc.] with the most important genre as Action > Crime > Drama > Thriller > etc. then I want my df to look like

```
df=
    Genre                              Cast
0   Action                             Brad P., Denzel W.
1   Crime                              Al P., Robert De N., Angelina J., Lupita N.
2   Action                             Mark W., Jamie F., Mila K.
3   Crime                              Jessica C.,Emma S.
4   Action                             Jennifer L., Tom H., Charlize H., Vin D., Denzel W.
5   Drama                              Tupac, George C., Kevin S.
```

Is that even possible in Pandas? Should I "fill" my lists with NaN for eg. so that they all have the same lengths within the df (how would that be done)?

Any help would be appreciated, I'm not even sure where to start on that one!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is my approach clearly explained:

```
df.Genre.str.split(', ').apply(lambda x : sorted(x, key=lambda y: order_list.index(y))[0])
```

- split all the gender into a list, you get a list or all gender,
- then sort all the list with the respect to the order of the genre in an order list( a list where all the genre is ordered)
- and finally get the first item in that list.

here is an example of your order list :

```
order_list = ['Action' ,  'Crime' , 'Drama' ,  'Thriller', 'Comedy','Romance', 'horror', 'Sci-fi', 'Adventure ', 'Adventure']
```